# AWS Performance Insight Huge Load from "Other" SQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, performance, sql

Engine: MySQL 5.7.26

Looking at my AWS Performance Insight metrics, I noticed that most of my Database load consumes the query marked "Other" Can I check what is hidden under this label?

Screenshot:

[image: Counter metrics]

Comment: Since the "others" seemed to track the one `SELECT` given, I recommend you work on improving that `SELECT` to see if the problem goes a way.